# SQL Server - using NULLIF with CONVERT to count multiple BIT fields

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this query:

```
SELECT 
    Percentages.ProjectID,
    SUM(Percentages.Percent1) + 
       SUM(Percentages.Percent2) /
       ISNULL(NULLIF(CONVERT(INT, Finances.IncludeP1), 0) + 
       NULLIF(CONVERT(INT, Finances.IncludeP2), 0), 1)
FROM
    Percentages
INNER JOIN 
    Finances ON Percentages.ProjectID = Finances.ProjectID
GROUP BY 
    Percentages.ProjectID
```

The way this works is like this, when fields (`Price1`) and (`Price2`) have a value that is not zero (so can be positive or negative), then the bit fields called (`IncludeP1`) and (`IncludeP2`) are TRUE(1)

As you can't divide by zero, I need the ability to NULL the VALUE of `IncludeP1` OR `IncludeP2` OR both. Then the `ISNULL` comes in as I want the original value to display so by dividing this by 1 gives be that desired result.

The error I am getting with the above query is due to the `Finances.IncludeP1` and `Finances.IncludeP2` not being included in the group statement however including them in this means the desired grouping of `ProjectID` does not work... is there a way to do this or do I need to rethink how this works?

Thanks for any help

[image]

Comment: sample data and desired output would help to clarify the problem here.

Comment: ok, ill add that in now

Comment: So you want to divide by the `COUNT` of IncludeP1?

Comment: Why are you grouping by ProjectID in your example it is not the case

Comment: yes, I want to divide by the Count of IncludeP1 for Percent1 (grouped by the ProjectID) and so on for the other 2 percentages

Comment: i am grouping them by ProjectID as there can be several sets of percentages under serveral ProjectID's. for example 10 Projects could be present

Comment: If you are grouping by projectid means how you got 150% for sum of percent1. It is sum of percent1 in projectid 1 and 2

Comment: the sum function adds both of the percentages together, so (100% + 50%) based on the group by ProjectID. as there is a value in both percentage fields i want to then divide this percentage by 2 to give me the average... in this case being 75%. for Percent2 then it would be (25% + 0%) / 1 as IncludeP2 is FALSE(0) for ProjectID 2

Answer (score 0):

solved it with the below query:

```
   SELECT 
    Finances.ProjectID,
    SUM(Finances.Percent1 + Finances.Percent2 + Finances.Percent3)
    /
    ISNULL(
           NULLIF(SUM(CASE WHEN (Finances.IncludeP1 = 1) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),0) +
           NULLIF(SUM(CASE WHEN (Finances.IncludeP2 = 1) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),0) +
           NULLIF(SUM(CASE WHEN (Finances.IncludeP3 = 1) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),0) 
        ,1)Answer,
    from Finances
    group by Finances.ProjectID
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ProjectID
      ,AVG([Percent])
FROM Finances
     CROSS APPLY (
         VALUES (PercentP1, IncludeP1)
               ,(PercentP2, IncludeP2)
               ,(PercentP3, IncludeP3)
     ) AS T([Percent], Include)
WHERE Include = 1
GROUP BY ProjectID
```